# Where should I write raw-query or query using query builder instead of writing it in route file in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-4

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class testing extends Model
{

}
```

should i write my all queries in this model class,even if i just want to use query builder no eloquent?

what are the good practices to write raw query or using query builder?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your queries or say eloquent in your model differenciating from other logical code

Say for example you have `AlbumController`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Album;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AlbumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $albums = Album::get_albums();
        // other logical code
    }
}
```

And in `Album.php` which is model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Album extends Model
{
     public static function get_albums() {
          $albums = Album::get();
          return $albums;
     }
}
```

And in your route file

```
Route::post('album', 'AlbumController@index');
```

Hope you get idea!

Comment: Thanks,Is there any further need to include (use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
) if i just want to use query builder no eloquent in model.

Comment: You will need to extend laravels inbuilt Model so you need to include (use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; )

Answer (score 0):

No that is not only the method to communicate with your database it is one possible solution only. You can use DB for query like

```
<?php
Namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
Class AbcController extends Controller{
Public function functionName(){
$data=DB::table(‘tableName’)->get();
return view(‘desiredPage’)->with(‘data’, $data);
}
}
```

[go to the link for more laravel database query information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database)

Comment: Is it good to write logical and query part in the same file,will it define MVC ?